# search array - php

Tags: php, arrays, search

Im trying to work out how to search a string looking for a given variable, and if it is longer than two charachters, and exists in the array, return that string with the search word highlighted in some way. Ive been trying for two days and its not coming out right, any help will be very welcome!

my php:

```
$search = $_POST    ['search']; 
$text = 'some long text containg several words.';

$search = trim($search);
$search = strtolower($search);

$text = explode($text);

if ((in_array($search, $text)) && ($search >= 2)){
    echo $text;
}else{
    echo "no result or too short search word";
}
```

and my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>word for which to search:</P>
    <form action="searchfunction.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search" /><br />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: so right now, thanks to Michael, the php looks like in Michaels example, but search result only says that any word is too short or not in array, even if i enter a word i know is in the array... Any thoughts as to why???

Comment: Check the actual `$_POST` the script receives with `var_dump($_POST);`

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no need to `explode()` into an array at all.  Just use `strpos()` to locate the search string and `strlen()` to make sure it's more than 2 characters.

```
$search = trim($_POST['search']); 
$text = 'some long text containg several words.';

// Search for $search inside $text as a string
// Both converted to lowercase only for the search    
if (strpos(strtolower($text), strtolower($search)) !== FALSE  && strlen($search) >= 2){
    echo $text;
}else{
    echo "no result or too short search word";
}
```

Now to handle your highlighting.  The easiest way to do that is to use `str_ireplace()` to surround it in a `<span>`. You would need to define the class 'highlight' in you CSS file to have some special color.

```
// If your text was found...
$text = str_ireplace($search, "<span class='highlight'>$search</span>", $text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: You forget `stripos()`, the case-insensitive version of `strpos()`, no need to convert to lowercase and it's shorter :p

Comment: @Arnar Yngvason Odd, and yet I remembered `str_ireplace` later on.

Comment: i can so see why this should work, but when i use it I only get the result I should be getting if the search word was too short or not in the array, even though i know it is...

Comment: @elin Make sure `$_POST` input is correctly received. If I test this code with `$search = 'text';` it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if ((in_array($search, $text)) && ($search >= 2)){
```

can you try

```
if ((in_array($search, $text)) && (strlen($search) >= 2)){
```

Also,
explode needs to take the first argument as " ". So you have to call it as

```
$text = explode(" ", $text)
```

Answer (score 0):

length function using in following line

```
if ((in_array($search, $text)) && ($search >= 2)){
```

in above line their is need some modifications

```
if ((in_array($search, $text)) && (strlen($search) >= 2)){
```

Answer (score 0):

explode() expects at least 2 parameters

```
$text = explode(' ', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
$text = explode($text);

if ((in_array($search, $text)) && ($search >= 2)){
```

...should be...

```
$text = explode(' ', $text);

if ((in_array($search, $text)) && (strlen($search) >= 2)){
```

It's also possible to achieve your goal without using arrays, for example by using a regular expression match:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
if (strlen($search) < 2) {
    echo "too short search word";
} else {
    $text = 'some long text containg several words.';
    $pattern = '/\b' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '\b/i';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches)) {
        echo $matches[0];
    } else {
        echo "no result";
    }
}
```